# Redirect directive in .htaccess file redirects to http protocol before redirecting to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have written following rewrite rule. It works fine but when I check in network tab I see two redirects instead of one. I am confused why do I get a http 307 redirect? Is there anything that I can change in my rule to eliminate 307 redirect?

- `https://example.com/page/about` => **301**
- `http://example.com/about.html` => **307**
- `https://example.com/about.html` => **200**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 /page/about /about.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are there any other redirect rules in your htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen no I don't have any other rule in htaccess.

Comment: Do you have access to the server/vHost config? The redirect to HTTP on the first redirect could perhaps be the result of a misconfiguration of your server? Although you should be able to override that by explicitly using an absolute URL as the target. And that should also prevent the 2nd 307 redirect. I would guess the 307 is being triggered by your application OR this is set in the vHost:80?

Comment: Btw, `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite, just in case you thought it was.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for replying. I have access to vHost but i was not sure what to change. So i changed Redirect directive with RewriteRule and hardcoded https part. Going to post what i did as an answer.

Comment: I would look for a `UseCanonicalName On` directive in the server config / virtualhost. However, it may not be as simple as setting that to `Off` (the default). (The _protocol_ as set in the `ServerName` directive (if any) might also be wrong.) And other rules might be making use of this?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue I changed Redirect directive with RewriteRule and hardcoded the https part.

```
RewriteRule "^page/about/?$"  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/about.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I would also expect changing the `Redirect` to `Redirect 301 /page/about https://example.com/about.html` would also resolve the issue (removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper - which is just unnecessary). Unless you already have other (mod_rewrite) `RewriteRule` directives in which case using another `RewriteRule` (as you have done) is advisable to avoid unexpected conflicts.

Comment: https://example.com/about.html cant do that cause cant hardcode the url. .htaccess file is being versioned and is being used in various environments.

Comment: Ah OK, `HTTP_HOST` and other server variables aren't available to mod_alias `Redirect` (and `RedirectMatch`) directives.